# Lack of disk space: Factory reset of dual booted Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, nvidia, python, tensorflow

Is it a **good idea** to make a **factory reset of ubuntu 20.04** (dual boot) due to lack of space? If so, **how** is it done?

Background: Tried installing tensorflow (following the step-by-step guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) but the tensorflow download, GPU setup, CUDA download- & installation left no space on my hard drive - tensorflow not even installed yet.

*Suspecting*: Due to my "do- and learn-approach" I have a lot of unnecessary packages, python versions etc. from 2-3 years back in time.

Personal experience (ubuntu commands/terminal): not beginner-level but faaaar from pro.

**Thanks in advance!**

## ==============
**Edited:**

[Disk usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M24d.png)

**Partitioning layout:**
Disk /dev/loop0: 68 KiB, 69632 bytes, 136 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop1: 68 KiB, 69632 bytes, 136 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop2: 133,24 MiB, 139706368 bytes, 272864 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop3: 131,94 MiB, 138330112 bytes, 270176 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop4: 113,91 MiB, 119418880 bytes, 233240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop5: 55,55 MiB, 58232832 bytes, 113736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop6: 2,55 MiB, 2658304 bytes, 5192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop7: 61,95 MiB, 64933888 bytes, 126824 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 238,49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: HFS256G39TND-N21
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0C13AAB5-F44C-47B0-87C3-8C97C8AFD625

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    206847    204800  100M EFI System
/dev/sda2     206848    239615     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     239616 335798271 335558656  160G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  498020352 500117503   2097152    1G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  335798272 498020351 162222080 77,4G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.

Disk /dev/loop8: 113,101 MiB, 119525376 bytes, 233448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop9: 162,89 MiB, 170778624 bytes, 333552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop10: 81,27 MiB, 85209088 bytes, 166424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop11: 2,55 MiB, 2658304 bytes, 5192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop12: 164,78 MiB, 172761088 bytes, 337424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop13: 169,43 MiB, 177647616 bytes, 346968 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop14: 55,53 MiB, 58212352 bytes, 113696 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop15: 50,98 MiB, 53432320 bytes, 104360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop16: 260,73 MiB, 273375232 bytes, 533936 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop17: 303,8 MiB, 317800448 bytes, 620704 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop18: 565,76 MiB, 593219584 bytes, 1158632 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop19: 99,48 MiB, 104304640 bytes, 203720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop20: 565,49 MiB, 592949248 bytes, 1158104 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop21: 322,92 MiB, 338583552 bytes, 661296 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop22: 54,24 MiB, 56872960 bytes, 111080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop24: 87,49 MiB, 91725824 bytes, 179152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop25: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop26: 346,83 MiB, 363659264 bytes, 710272 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop27: 99,48 MiB, 104304640 bytes, 203720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop28: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop29: 169,58 MiB, 177803264 bytes, 347272 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop30: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop31: 322,97 MiB, 338636800 bytes, 661400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop32: 87,7 MiB, 91942912 bytes, 179576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop33: 303,8 MiB, 317796352 bytes, 620696 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop34: 61,94 MiB, 64925696 bytes, 126808 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop35: 400,82 MiB, 420265984 bytes, 820832 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop36: 254,1 MiB, 266436608 bytes, 520384 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop37: 91,7 MiB, 96141312 bytes, 187776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop38: 346,9 MiB, 363724800 bytes, 710400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Comment: What do you mean by *factory reset*.  If your machine came with a *factory reset* option, the maker of the machine will know what it does; we can only speculate given we have no idea what brand & model equipment you have & thus what they've put into their *factory reset*.  (Ubuntu has no such function; it's an OS & not a manufacturer).

Comment: I meant some kind of system reset of Ubuntu. My laptop (Acer Swift-SF314-52G) came installed with windows and I've set up Ubuntu as a dual boot myself. So my question is if it is possible to reset it to its status when I just had "dual booted" it?

Much appreciate the quick answer!

Comment: You can re-install Ubuntu.  How you re-install will dictate if it's like a new install (ie. *clean* install) or configuration/packages will be re-installed (*dirty* or *unclean* install), but the later may also result in the problem you have no re-occurring & failure to install due to space issues...  Factory reset is a machine specific operation in your case setup by Acer & will include only the windows it came with (no Ubuntu).

Comment: FYI:  If it was me I'd use *unclean* install to achieve what you want, but it'll be unlikely to work if you've been *learning as you go* as it requires all requires all mistakes when made, to be corrected (ie. packages installed removed & any changes to how installed; *manually installed* etc flags) be reset manually during the *fix*, for it to be successful.  In your case it may not help, unless you *fix* your system before you re-install, and use the re-install to get a *new* fixed system.  Make sure you allocate sufficient disk space - the doco is there for a reason, to avoid space issues

Comment: There is no such thing as "factory reset" in Ubuntu. If you mean to return the system to the state it was just after installing, then the way to do it is to reinstall the system again.

Comment: If you installed Ubuntu in 1 partition, you can transfer your documents, downloads, music and videos to another disk to create space. This won't clean up the OS though. To make a clean(er) system, write down what you need and what you installed and configurations, and then make a clean install. Download and install what you need, change your configurations, and you have a clean, working system with more diskspace. Or you can use GParted to reconfigure your partitions. ( Make backups first. )

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers! @guiverc, then I think a *clean* installation will suit me best. Do you know of a good online guide (step-by-step) for this?

Comment: @user535733, yes on being a XY-question.. I've updated my post according to your requests. At the moment a big portion of my disk usage is occupied by image data sets (the reason I needed tensorflow was to analyze these) which I'm aware are very large, my problem is the storage "taken" by python, packages, etc that's piled up. The db is not the reason for 0 space, it has been working fine 2-3 years back.

Comment: @user535733, how does GParted work? To me it feels like "another thing to learn/read up on and which seems to use storage"? But that's my skepticism taking over due to trying to fix this (in multiple ways) for too long now.

Comment: Your `fdisk` output says that your entire disk (sda) is 238GB, but your `df` output says your sda5  root (/) partition is only 79GB. Is the rest of the space on your disk accounted for? It's a basic question, but it's amazing how many users learn that most of their disk is simply unformatted and unused.

Comment: Were I in your shoes, I would use the `du` command to see what the big non-database files on the machine are. It could be as simple as a runaway logfile, or files hidden behind a mount point, or a forgotten mail spool, or kernel source code from experimenting with compiling, or other easy fixes. Packages tend to be tiny and laborious to weed through, so look for lower-hanging fruit first.

Comment: Alternately, if this is a Desktop, using Disk Usage Analyzer may be simpler. DUA is included with every stock install of Ubuntu, so you likely have it already.

Comment: Thanks @user535733! As I've mentioned I also have Windows OS but I'm not sure how many GB's allocated for it (if that's even possible) but I'm quite sure this is where the remaining space "sits". Should space accounted for by windows also occur when applying df while in ubuntu? 

I've examined with help of DUA already and it's good for overview I think, the same was the du command (a new one for me, I used *du -sh -- * | sort -h
*). I think my main problem is I have a LOT of files that are not LARGE by themselves - but together they use a lot of space, hence my idea of a ubuntu reset...